# What's reason for getting time limit exceeded error with my knapsack code?

Tags: java

This is the code which I have written to print the maximum value that can be put in a knapsack of capacity W.If given weights and values available.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String s1=sc.nextLine();
        String s2=sc.nextLine();
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        String[] s3=s1.split(" ");
        String[] s4=s2.split(" ");
        int[] values=new int[s3.length];
        int[] weights=new int[s4.length];
        for(int i=0;i<s3.length;i++){             //extracting values from a string array
            values[i]=Integer.parseInt(s3[i]);
            weights[i]=Integer.parseInt(s4[i]);
        }
        int res=0;
        while(n>0){
            double max=-1;
            int maxi=0;
            for(int i=0;i<values.length;i++){
                if(weights[i]>0&&max<(double)weights[i]/values[i]){
                    max=(double)weights[i]/values[i];
                    maxi=i;
                }
            }
            if(weights[maxi]<=n){
                n=n-weights[maxi];
                res=res+values[maxi];
            }
            weights[maxi]=0;
            
        }
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

I was getting a time limit exceeded error and wrong answer for hidden test cases. can anyone help me to find out the loop holes in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard dynamic programming problem, where the solution for the entire problem depends on subproblems; it cannot be solved with a greedy algorithm like you are trying to use. Let `maxVal[i]` denote the maximum value that a knapsack with capacity `i` can hold, `values[i]` represent the value of the `i`th item, and `weights[i]` represent the weight of the `i`th item. Then, for each `i`, `maxVal[i]` is the maximum of `maxVal[i - weights[j]] + values[j]` for all `j` from 1 to the number of items.

The base case here is `maxVal[0] = 0`. You can then loop over all the items, and apply the formula described above. The final answer will be `maxVal[n]`, where `n` is the capacity of the knapsack.

It is also important to note that [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and [`String#split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) are quite slow and you will be better off using [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and [`StringTokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
    StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
    int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    int[] maxVal = new int[n + 1];
    while (st1.hasMoreTokens()) {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(st1.nextToken());
        int weight = Integer.parseInt(st2.nextToken());
        for (int i = n; i >= weight; i--) {
            maxVal[i] = Math.max(maxVal[i], maxVal[i - weight] + value);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(maxVal[n]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have a doubt. Why my code did not pass all the test cases for my approach?

Comment: @SasiRekhaMurakonda You were trying to apply a greedy algorithm for a dynamic programming program. Also, you were using `Scanner` and `String#split` which are quite slow.